# Separate "domain user" from "authentication user" with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

My previous Rails apps have ended up with bloated user model with a thousand has_many associations and a whole bunch of domain-specific code and attributes in the user model.

In the next app, I am thinking about separating the model that I use for authentication (with devise) from the domain-specific model that I use for the rest of the app.

Something like this:

```
class User
  devise :database_authenticatable, :etc
  has_one :domain_user      
end

class DomainUser
  belongs_to :user      
end
```

Controllers would have an accessor to make access to the domain user easy and most of the app would not care about the authentication model at all.

```
class ApplicationController
  def domain_user
    current_user.domain_user
  end
end
```

As well as avoiding the bloat of putting everything into one model, I hope to end up with an authentication sub-system that I can reuse in future apps.

Is this a good idea? Is there a better way to approach this? What pitfalls should I look out for?

Comment: I am using a `profile` setting for your `domain_user` use case, thus making `User` a scope for all of his resources accessible within the app, and his `Profile` for accessing settings. As a result - `User` is only for authentication and as a global in-app scope. If you need to do some changes in the user's settings - go for `Profile`. Your approach sounds good, the only thing is be careful upon creation, you'll have to rewrite a bit of Devise, and wrap in DB transactions everything, so that you are totally sure that your `user` has a `domain_user`